# Difference between average induced emf and emf in a loop with angular velocity w?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-induction

The question says that a loop with area $A$ and $N$ turns moves $\pi$ radians in 0.15 secs in a magnetic field $B$. Find the average induced emf in 0.15 secs.

I calculated the angular velocity from this as $\omega = \pi/0.15$, and the flux becomes $NBA\cos\omega t$, and emf becomes $NBA\omega\sin\omega t$.
How do I calculate the average emf from this equation, because at $t=0.15$, the emf is zero?
I know I can simply calculate it from ($\Delta$flux /$\Delta$time), but I want to know what's wrong with my method.

Answer (score 0):

Just considering start and end EMF values won't allow you to calculate the average of the sinusoidally varying EMF. To calculate the average emf you would need to integrate $\epsilon = -NBA \omega \sin \omega t$ with respect to time and divide by $\Delta t$. The resulting expression will be equivalent to $\Delta$ flux / $\Delta t$.